# How to make complete date from month and year in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, datetime

I have stored years and months in separate columns in MySQL. Now I want to combine them to make a complete date, like if I have **2022** stored in year column and **3** stored in month column, I want to extract the complete date like **'2022-03-01'**, where the day starts from first date of the month. I am doing so that I could compare the resulting date with date attribute sent from the HTML form.

I have already tried

```
date_add(makedate(f.year, f.month), interval (f.month)-1 month) \>= starting_date

date_add(makedate(f.year, f.month), interval (f.month)-1 month) \<= ending_date
```

but this does not return the desired output.

Comment: I get the idea but going forward, you'll definitely end up with a very slow query. If you want to optimize, create a proper date column that accepts year-month-day so you can take advantage of the MySQL date functions.

Comment: `makedate` wants the year and the _day of the year_ as parameters. You could use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) though, if you concatenate your year, month and `1` to a date string first.

Comment: Let's say you have a field as `my_date`, which is a date type: `YYYY-MM-DD H:I:S`, then you can do: `my_date BETWEEN $min_date AND $max_date` => ``my_date BETWEEN 2022-03-10 00:00:00 AND 2022-04-10 00:00:00`

Comment: Also, is it compulsory for you to split the year, month, and day into separate columns in your database? Otherwise, there's no need for this, use a proper date type then. Also, if you want to use the year, month, and day in PHP directly, there are numerous ways to achieve this.